# SAP Business Objects error

Tags: business-objects

I am getting an error in SAP BusinessObjects
Central Management Console

"Account information not recognized: Could not reach CMS "***********". The CMS on machine '**********' was stopped due to a critical error. (FWM 20031)

Please help me out in fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

The CMS is stopped; try starting it.  If it still doesn't start, check the server event logs.

Comment: how could we fix it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most commonly seen with Custom data sources used for SAP BI deployment.

CMS database user password has been changed and when to try to update in the SIA, it throws the error stating the account is locked.

We have to unlock the CMS database user credentials from the database and change the password in SIA (Server Intelligence Agent) to fix the issue.